# Chat Application - Best way

Tags: php, real-time

I'd like my website to have chat/group chat functionality. Site is built using php/mysql.

I have implemented client side chat screen. I am fairly good with JavaScript/jQuery and AJAX.
When user enters message it is saved to the database using AJAX call. When servers responds with success I update chat window with the message user just entered.

Now the problem is here.
Suppose two persons A and B are chatting.
A enters a message, it is saved into database and chat window is updated.
Now how come B will know that A has sent a message.

Solution I can think of is B need to "poll" server continuously after 1 or 2 seconds. But for some reason I don't think that's the right/best approach.

Is "polling" the server a best way or is there certain other approach that I don't know of?

I am ready implement this(chat app) in some other language/technology also, only thing is it should work on my php site.

I just want to know what is the best way to design this chat app for my PHP website.

**P.S. please don't suggest any third party chat libraries. I am ready to code whatever it takes to build it.**

Comment: One of the great things about open-source libraries is that you can read their code to learn from them. While you don't want to use third-party chat libraries for some reason, you certainly should look at them to see how they work.

Comment: It doesn't have to be every 1-2 seconds. Set "polling" to short period if the chat is "freshy" and make period's time longer as function of idle time. For example, refresh the chat window every 3-5 secs after the last message, then, if idle, make the refresh rate 30 secs and so on...

Comment: By the way, it's great you want to write your own script! That's why I'm not using jQuery =) +1!

Comment: @derobert - sure I'd look at them to learn from them... :) The point is I don't want to USE them on my site. I am more interested in approach than actual solution.

Comment: @MichaelSazonov

So I need to set the polling interval depending on "activity status" of user...

Comment: @TriNitroToluene that's what I'd do...

Answer (score 2):

If you are comfortable with JavaScript I think you should take a look at [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/).
There's even a good example of a chat written in node (which you can browse the code on github) [here](http://chat.nodejs.org/).

Even if you prefer doing the server side in PHP, I think the client side of this implementation may be a good guiding example.

Answer (score 0):

**Polling**

This is the only way if you're using http and javascript. Http (and ajax) is single directional, the client *always* initiates the interaction with an action.

The only way to implement it without polling is to use a third party plugin (flash/silverlight/java) which allow a socket connection or go to a native application outside the browser.

Edit:
I wasn't aware of http push, however I'm not convinced it is a practical approach to the problem.

http://ejohn.org/blog/streaming-http-server-push/

Comment: I personally think using socket connection will be efficient as compared to scheduled polling.

Is it possible to use Java in combination with PHP? Any link(s) to learn about it?

Comment: HTTP has supported server push since, ummm, Netscape 1.x days. The fish cam used it, after all.